# Etymology of the meaning of waste as a broad expanse

Tags: etymology

Merriam-Webster online dictionary says one of the meanings of "waste" is:
a broad and empty expanse(as of water)
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waste

I'm interested in the origin of this meaning.
Let me explain why.

Here's from *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 2.

> In the dead wast and middle of the night

This is from Second Quarto and First Folio.
In the modern spelling, "wast" is "waste".

However, in First Quarto, "wast" is replaced by "vast".
My wild guess is that the pronunciation of "vast" and "wast" were the same in the Elizabethan English. Hence the printers of *Hamlet* at that time mistook "vast" as "wast".
They say First Quarto is unreliable, but it's the oldest text of *Hamlet*.

In any case, my question is: What is the origin of the meaning of "waste" as a broad expanse?

Comment: Consulting a dictionary will give the etymology.

Comment: @RoaringFish Which dictionary? Could you please name one?

Comment: Just look for the word 'etymological' on the dictionary - they are not rare! Online... I use OED, or if I can't be bothered going through the log in process I use Collins online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=waste&searchmode=none), the etymology of this sense of waste is:

> ***waste***: *c.1300, of land, "**desolate, uncultivated**," from Anglo-French and Old North French waste (Old French gaste), from Latin vastus (see waste (v.)). From c.1400 as "**superfluous, excess**;" 1670s as "**unfit for use.**" Waste-paper attested from 1580s.*

In other words, *all that space is **wasted***. Because, conceptually, one or more of the following applies:

- ***No one is using it***, i.e. it's more than is needed
- ***No one can use it***, e.g. for farming, because it's **unfit**
- It's been ***used up***, i.e., it is dried out, arid.
- It's covered in ***rubble*** (garbage).

Re: your speculation about *vast*, yes, they share a common origin in the Latin word:

> [***vastus***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vast&searchmode=none): *a **lot** of **empty** (wasted) space*.

But note the senses and etymologies of the two derived words -- *vast* and *waste* -- diverged about three centuries before *Hamlet* was written.

---

<sup>Aside: one of the most moving statements in the English language occurred when a reporter asked Buzz Aldrin (the second man on the Moon) what the Moon was *like*, and he replied:</sup>

> <sup>***Beautiful. Beautiful. [Magnificent desolation](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Buzz_Aldrin).***</sup>

Comment: The Latin word "vastus" has two different meanings "immense" and "devastated", though they are not entirely unrelated.
It is clear that the main meaning of "vast" was originated from the former,
while the main meaning of "waste" was originated from the latter.
As you pointed out, the online etymology dictionary says about the meaning of "waste" that c.1200, "desolate regions" from Latin vastum, neuter of vastus "waste".
It is not clear to me when "waste" had the meaning "immense".

Comment: @ivanhoescott, I think you're restating what I said in my answer (and we're both just restating what we read on etymonline), no? If not, I'm genuinely happy to update, edit, or improve it, if you can itemize the changes you're suggesting.

Comment: I guess you are right. The word "waste" had almost the same meaning as "vastus" from the first.